# SVG Linear Gradient Size isn't changing in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, gradient, linear-gradients

I've got a problem with my Linear Gradient created with SVG. I can't extend it past 250 pixels, or so, in Firefox.
Here's what I've got so far.

```
    <svg>
       <defs>
          <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
             <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0, 124, 57);stop-opacity:1" />
         <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0, 100, 47);stop-opacity:1" />
          </linearGradient>
   </defs>
   <rect width="" height="34" fill="url(#grad1)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you explain what size you need?

Comment: How big is your outermost `<svg>` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `<svg>` element to be `<svg height="100%" width="100%">`